# Replace a Polygon in a Spatial Polygon Data Frame

Tags: r, gis

I have a spatial polygon dataframe with several shapefiles. I would like to trim these shapefiles by elevation and replace the original shapefile in the dataframe. However, there appears to be an error when I try to replace the polygon after the trim. Currently, my plan is run though the following loop for each shapefile in the dataset. However, when I try `dist[i,] <- temp3`, I get the following error:

Error in match(value, lx) : 'match' requires vector arguments
In addition: Warning message:
In checkNames(value) :
  attempt to set invalid names: this may lead to problems later on. See ?make.names

Any suggestions?

```
# Load spdf
dist <- rgdal::readOGR('critterDistributions.shp');

# Load elevational ranges
rangeElevation <- read.csv(file = 'elevationRanges.csv');

# Load altitude data
elevation <- raster('ETOPO1_Bed_g_geotiff.tif');

# Tidy up CRSes
crs(elevation) <- crs(dist);

# Run loop
for (i in 1:length(dist)){
  subjName <- as.character(dist@data$Species[i]);
  if (!(subjName %in% rangeElevation$?..Species_name)){
    paste0(subjName, 'does not exist in the elevational range database.');
  }
  else{
    erNameMatch <- match(subjName, rangeElevation$?..Species_name);
    temp <- raster::reclassify(elevation, rcl = c(-Inf,rangeElevation[erNameMatch,2],NA, 
                                                  rangeElevation[erNameMatch,2],rangeElevation[erNameMatch,3],1, 
                                                  rangeElevation[erNameMatch,3],Inf,NA));
    temp2 <- dist[i,];
    temp <- mask(temp, temp2);
    temp <- crop(temp, temp2);
    temp3 <- rasterToPolygons(temp, na.rm = T, dissolve = T);
    names(temp3) <- make.names(names(temp2), unique = T);
    temp3@data <- temp2@data;
    dist[i,] <- temp3; # <<<< This is the line of code that doesn't work.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hannah, please make sure your question is reproducible so that others can help. Plus, what is the error message?

Comment: Hi Majid, unfortunately, I couldn't identify a good set of dummy data for anyone to reproduce. I have edited my original question to include the error message, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further thought, I came up with a workaround: initiating a list, then using rbind after the loop to unite everything back together into a single object. I'm still interested in finding out why `dist[i,] <- temp3` doesn't work, but at least I was able to get this job done.

```
oneSPDFtoRuleThemAll <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(dist));
for (i in 1:length(dist)){
  subjName <- as.character(dist@data$Species[i]);
  if (!(subjName %in% rangeElevation$?..Species_name)){
    paste0(subjName, 'does not exist in the elevational range database.');
  }
  else{
    erNameMatch <- match(subjName, rangeElevation$?..Species_name);
    temp <- raster::reclassify(elevation, rcl = c(-Inf,rangeElevation[erNameMatch,2],NA, 
                                                  rangeElevation[erNameMatch,2],rangeElevation[erNameMatch,3],1, 
                                                  rangeElevation[erNameMatch,3],Inf,NA));
    temp2 <- dist[i,];
    temp <- mask(temp, temp2);
    temp <- crop(temp, temp2);
    temp3 <- rasterToPolygons(temp, na.rm = T, dissolve = T);
    names(temp3) <- make.names(names(temp2), unique = T);
    temp3@data <- temp2@data;
    oneSPDFtoRuleThemAll[[i]] <- temp3; # <<<< This is the line of code that doesn't work.
  }
}

finalSPDF <- rbind(unlist(oneSPDFtoRuleThemAll));
```